# JQuery mouseleave function for dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, animation, menu

I'm trying to create an animated dropdown menu using Jquery/CSS and have the animation to make it appear fine, but I need it to hide the drop down menu onmouseout, however just using onmouseout won't work with the ul, when I hover over an li it triggers it. Having read other posts I though I could use the JQuery mouseleave function but can't egt it working, can anyone help!?

The menu:

```
<ul id="navList">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="about" onmouseover="dropDown();" ><a href="#">About me</a>
            <ul id="drop">
                <li>What I do</li>
                <li>CV</li>
                <li>Photo Gallery</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The function that shows the dropdown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dropDown () 
{

            $("#drop").animate({height:'100px'},300);
            $("#drop").animate({opacity:'100'},300);

};
</script>
```

The function I'm trying to use to hide it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#about').mouseleave(function(){
$("#drop").animate({height:'0px'},300);
$("#drop").animate({opacity:'0'},300);  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Just Try With The Following :***

**Script Part :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dropDown () 
{
$("#drop").show().animate({height:'100px'},300).animate({opacity:'100'},300);
}
function mouseOut()
{
$("#drop").animate({height:'0px'},300).animate({opacity:'0'},300);
}
$(function() {
$("#drop").hide();
$("#about a").hover(dropDown,mouseOut);
});
</script>
```

**HTML Part :**

```
<ul id="navList">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="#">About me</a>
            <ul id="drop">
                <li>What I do</li>
                <li>CV</li>
                <li>Photo Gallery</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.